# Firebase Method to check whether an email is already associated with an account

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication

Desired behavior:

I would like to have a method that verify the email address with firebase to throw some error if the email is used/invalid.

`createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` does not seem to do the job as I would only want to create the account if the user passes a phone verification on the second page, but I would like to throw some error before the user navigates to the second page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a backend that can use the Admin SDK, you can implement your own API to do this by following https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data

```
admin
  .auth()
  .getUserByEmail(email)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // return error 
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // allow going to second page
  });
```